# How do I insert data in Laravel database from controller?

Tags: laravel, insert

this is my first post in this forum and also I'm a very new user with Laravel.
I'm trying to do a very simple thing like creating an array and visualize the data inside in my database. The code works but I cant see the data in the database table. It might look easy but for some reason I've been a whole day with this thing so I'll appreciate a lot any help I can receive. This is how the code looks right now:

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Client;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ClientController extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
       DB::table('clients')->insert(
           array(
                  'id'     =>   1, 
                  'name'   =>   'Josh',
                  'age'   =>   45,
                  'gender'   =>   'M',
                  'nationality'   =>   'UK',
                  'job'   =>   'a',
           )
       );
   }

}
```

**Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{  
    use HasFactory; 

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'age', 'gender', 'nationality', 'job',
    ];

}
```

**Migration:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateClientsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('age');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('nationality');
            $table->string('job');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('clients');
    }
}
```

Comment: `DB::table('clients')->insert(...)` doesn't use the ORM. Since you have a Client Model with a `$fillable` property, you should use `Client::create(...)` instead.  Since the `id` is filled by the database, you don't need to pass it in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your migration change this line:

```
 $table->bigIncrements('id');
```

with

```
$table->id();
```

Once you have migrated it with:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh (empty database and recreate it)
```

Insert a record with:

```
public function index()
{
Client::create([
    'name'   =>   'Josh',
    'age'   =>   45,
    'gender'   =>   'M',
    'nationality'   =>   'UK',
    'job'   =>   'a',
]);
}
```

There is no need to populate the id. Laravel (MySQL) will do it for you.

Comment: Only the last part of the answer is relevant. [`id()` just calls `bigIncrements('id')`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php#L605)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you do not need "," at the end of the array

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'age', 'gender', 'nationality', 'job',
];
```